# Is there a clearer way to deal with fields that are not in aggregate functions or the GROUP BY clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, aggregation

I often run into situations where I have a query like this:

```
SELECT
    a.Id,
    a.A,
    a.B,
    a.C,
    SUM(b.Foo) AS foo
FROM
    TableA AS a
    JOIN TableB AS b
        ON a.Id = b.TableAId
GROUP BY a.Id;
```

In SQL Server (and also MySQL if `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is true), this query is no good.  Everything needs to be either a) in an aggregate function, or b) in the `GROUP BY`.

My problem is that both solutions look bad and misleading.  If you pick a random aggregate function like `MAX()` you end up with:

```
SELECT
    a.Id,
    MAX(a.A) AS A,
    MAX(a.B) AS B,
    MAX(a.C) AS C,
    SUM(b.Foo) AS foo
FROM
    TableA AS a
    JOIN TableB AS b
        ON a.Id = b.TableAId
GROUP BY a.Id;
```

This query looks like we care about the max values of `a.A`, `a.B` and `a.C`, and obfuscates the fact that the max is meaningless.

`GROUP BY` is a little bit better:

```
SELECT
    a.Id,
    a.A,
    a.B,
    a.C,
    SUM(b.Foo) AS foo
FROM
    TableA AS a
    JOIN TableB AS b
        ON a.Id = b.TableAId
GROUP BY a.Id, A, B, C;
```

but it still isn't optimal. In a big query with complex grouping, having all these extra fields makes it harder to read, and my initial impression is that there's some extra grouping hierarchy here that doesn't actually exist.

My background is mostly in MySQL with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` turned off, so I find this restriction in SQL Server to be unnecessary.  I wish there was some happy medium between the two; it seems like a simple thing for a computer to look at this query and see that the `TableA` fields don't need to be aggregated, while any field from `TableB` (besides `TableAId`) does.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's not silly.  It's the correct logic.  MySQL implementation is the one broken.

Comment: Even your example is flawed.  You are only group by `a.Id`.  So in this case, MySQL arbitrarily choose one value of `a.A`, `a.B`, and `a.C` for you, you won't know which one.

Comment: In fact, MySQL is probably the only dbms system that allow this broken logic.

Comment: @Eric But we do know which one, because we know that `TableA` is unique on `Id`.  So there's nothing broken at all about just returning any ol' `a.A` -- they're guaranteed to be the same.

Comment: If `Id` is unique, then what's wrong with `GROUP BY a.Id, a.A, a.B, a.C`?

Comment: @Eric, I think the objection is that if `Id` is unique, it should not be necessary to GROUP BY those other columns, because there can be only one row in `TableA` per value of `Id`, therefore only one possible value of the other columns in each group.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a SQL Server problem!  The behavior you see is MySQL broken-ness (in general), which is why the default now is to disallow that behavior.  That said, aggregating by a unique column in a table and selecting other columns in the table *is* allowed by the SQL standard.  However, I think only Postgres implements this.

Here is one method you left out:

```
SELECT a.*, b.foo
FROM TableA a JOIN
     (SELECT b.TableAId, SUM(b.Foo) as foo
      FROM TableB b
      GROUP BY b.TableAId
     ) b
     ON a.Id = b.TableAId;
```

Comment: Won't your solution prevent the index from working?  I guess I don't see why it would, but indexes can be finicky when joining to derived tables.

Comment: @JasonHamje . . . It will not prevent an index on `a(id)` from being used.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL 5.7 and later handles this quite well:

```
mysql [localhost:5724] {msandbox} (test) > select @@sql_mode;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                                                                                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql [localhost:5724] {msandbox} (test) > SELECT
    ->     a.Id,
    ->     a.A,
    ->     a.B,
    ->     a.C,
    ->     SUM(b.Foo) AS foo
    -> FROM
    ->     TableA AS a
    ->     JOIN TableB AS b
    ->         ON a.Id = b.TableAId
    -> GROUP BY a.Id;
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

See, no error!

Because this query is grouping by a unique key of `TableA`, it can tell the other columns of `TableA` have a functional dependency on the column you're grouping by. So there's no need to spew errors about ambiguous results.

The only column in the select-list that doesn't have a functional dependency on the grouping column is `b.Foo`, which in this query is safely inside an aggregate function.

So MySQL, while it used to leave it up to the developer to know how to write queries that avoided ambiguity, now has two improvements, both implemented in MySQL 5.7.5 (2014-09-25):

1. ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled by default
2. MySQL analyzes functional dependencies, and does not give the developer grief if your unaggregated columns are functionally dependent on the grouping column.

These improvements have been generally available in MySQL for 3.5 years (it's April 2019 as I write this, and 5.7 went GA in October 2015). How many years will it take before MySQL gets credit for this improvement?

P.S. I don't know which other RDBMS products can do the functional dependency analysis correctly.